# Parsing JSON and Make New Object With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

How Can I Take `id` From `survey_answer` json and Inset That in id2 Column?, with php and mysql
[image: Photo]

This is My Code:

```
       <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayy");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT `survey_answers` FROM `user_survey_start`";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $json = $row[0];
        $jason_array  = json_decode($json,true);

        // id   
        $id = array();
        foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
            $id[] = $data['id'];
            // here code to insert/update values to db column
        }
        echo implode(',',$id)."</br>";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: use `var_dump($json_array);` and paste it here. and can you explain  what is expected output and what are you getting

Comment: Why are you using json_decode?? you are not getting any json response in your while loop

Comment: I'm New, Can You Correct my Code Please... I want to parse id and put in id2

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: don't add someone's answer in you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code after for loop:

```
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayy");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
    $sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,id_s FROM `user_survey_start`";
        //.........yor code
                foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
                    $id[] = $data['id'];
                }
                $ids= implode(',',$id);
                $sql1="update user_survey_start set id2='$ids' where id_s=".$row[1];//run update sql
                mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
```

**Note:** Add where clause in update sql for each row(like where rowId=$id).

Comment: I Added This Code But Id2 is Empty Still

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei what is the primary key of your table.

Comment: I have `id_s`  AI

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei  check the update.First check whether you are getting data of each row or not.

Comment: Can You Connect with team viewer and see my Code? Please

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei sorry man i'm in office.just put `echo  $sql1."<br>";` before `mysqli_query($con,$sql1);` and run your code and see what it prints.and run the printed sql in phpmyadmin to see id it is right or not.

Comment: Yessssssss, Solved, Apriciate Itttttttt

Comment: One More Question, Why Your Code Print 2 Time, `update user_survey_start set id2='26,30,31,32,33,26,30,31,32,33' where id_s=1` That Repeat '26,30,31,32,33, Solveddddd